# How do I get a single observable from multiple observables in this scenario?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Here is my situation. I have a form that spans across multiple tabs and holds two values, `numberOfUsers`, which is a number and `users` which is an array of user data(id, name, address, city).

Each tab is created dynamically and has a repeating formGroup named 'user' which is part of a formArray.
Each tab can hold a maximum of 3 user formGroups.

What I would like to do is update my main form `users` array with the values of all the created user groups.
Right now, I have a different form in each tab holding the different user data. I use a dynamic BehaviorSubject in a service to collect and transmit the data from the secondary forms. Here is the service:

```
export class BroadcasterService {

    // subject 
    protected _eventsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
      constructor() {
      }
    broadcast(key: any, value: any) {
        this._eventsSubject.next({ key, value }); // here we are setting the key and value of our subject
    }

    on<T>(key: any): Observable<T> {
        return this._eventsSubject.asObservable()
            .pipe(

                filter(e => e.key === key),
                map(e => e.value)
            );
    }
```

Every form sets its `key` and passes its `value` to the `behaviorSubject` like this:

```
 onChanges(): void {
       this.usersArray.valueChanges
            .subscribe(val => {
                this.broadcaster.broadcast('BIS_' + this.tabNumber, val);
            }); 

    }
```

Then on my main component, I subscribe to all the observables and I assume I have to concatenate or merge them or do something else in order to get a single observable that updates the `users` formArray on my main form. Here is what I am doing:

```
  let main: Observable<[]> = this.broadcaster.on("Main");
  let bis1: Observable<[]> = this.broadcaster.on("BIS_1");
  let bis2: Observable<[]> = this.broadcaster.on("BIS_2");

  Observable.concat(main, bis1, bis2).subscribe(values => {

                                              values.forEach(value => {

                                                        this.addUser();
                                              });

                                              this.usersArray.patchValue( values );

  });
```

Apparently, I am doing something very wrong. I am new to rxjs. I don't even know if this approach is the right one...
I get multiple subscriptions with null values and depending on the order of the observables in the concatenated observable, I get different results. Could anybody help me on this one...?

Here is a blitz, for a better understanding.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bis-tabs

Comment: For starters, you definitely want to use `merge` instead of `concat.